# IBM websphere portal programatic page creation

Tags: java, portlet, portal, websphere-portal, spring-portlet-mvc

I am asked to Create a Portal Website on a Button Click

When a button is clicked on Portlet i have to Create a Page and add content and theme to it programatically using the action method of that portlet

However i am not able to find how to do this using java.

Wherever i have seen i could see how to do it on Websphere Portal Admin
I am using http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/ and http://www-10.lotus.com/ for reference and not able to find how to do this .

For example from UI http:localhost:10039/wps/portal 
i can do the same by following steps
1. Click on Administration
2. Click on Manage Pages
3. Create new Page
4. Select default Theme for page
5. goto page
6. Add Content or Portlets

Server used: IBM websphere Portal 8.5
Technology: Java /Spring/Portlet

I am still not sure if portletfactory can do the same work as i am totally new To this so can someone guide on how to move forward

Expected End result: create a portal website with few dynamic portlets created on a button click based on some inputs and the website should be saved on a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, but I was finally able to solve this issue with the help of a post by Georgy Gobozov. I used the Migration Script Created by him to handle the page creation -
[Page Create Code and Copy](http://pastebin.com/Tva0Za8H).

This really helped me in solving the issue. With this I was able to create pages on runtime and add portlets to them on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the Controller SPIs for what you want to do.  Here are links to the documentation: 
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dev/ctrlrapic_ovu.html
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dev/ctrlrapit_crt_rsrc.html

Comment: Please post at least the gist of the solution into your answer. As it stands, this answer will become useless if and when ibm.com moves those pages to a different URL or otherwise changes anything about those pages.